# How to get custom attribute value in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer

How to get custom attribute value  in magento2

Comment: custom attribute of customer or product?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to search his id and his backend_type with this query:

```
select a.attribute_id, a.attribute_code, a.backend_type 
from eav_attribute as a
inner join eav_entity_type as e on (a.entity_type_id = e.entity_type_id)
where e.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product';
```

The **entity_type_code** field can be 'catalog_product' for product attributes, 'customer' for customer attributes or 'customer_address' for customer address attributes.

The query will return a set of all attributes linked to a product in magento (default and custom attributes):

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| attribute_id | attribute_code                 | backend_type |
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|          429 | allow_message                  | int          |
|          399 | allow_open_amount              | int          |
|          578 | brand                          | int          |
|          590 | bundle_price                   | varchar      |
|          581 | bundle_qta                     | varchar      |
|          593 | categoria                      | int          |
                          ...
```

After you found the `attribute_id` and the `backend_type` of your attribute you can select his values in on of the `catalog_product_entity` tables (depends on the backend type of your attribute).

```
sql table                       | backend type
--------------------------------|---------------
catalog_product_entity_int      | int 
catalog_product_entity_varchar  | varchar 
catalog_product_entity_decimal  | decimal
                           ...
```

For example if your attribute has the is **578** and the backend_type of **int**, you  execute a query like this one:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 578
```